# What is the equivalent of Java static methods in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, static, static-methods

There is no `static` keyword in Kotlin.

What is the best way to represent a `static` Java method in Kotlin?

Comment: Use a [package-level function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#companion-objects).

Comment: **Be advised:** Kotlin has removed Java-style statics to encourage more maintainable (dare I say 'better') coding practices.  Static globals are generally against the OOP-paradigm but they can be quite convenient. Hence, Kotlin has provided us with [companions, a more OOP-friendly way of having statics.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#companion-objects)

Comment: @NicholasMiller why is it more OOP-friendly? I think it is easier to read and write without the recurring note of static (boilerplate). Or is there another good reason?

Comment: At first glance this looks to be precisely the companion class of Scala. That follows my impression: `kotlin` is a simpler _scala_ . This is good.

Comment: @TorbenG. The boilerplate code is an educational barrier you get punished with everytime you use a global static. Modern languages are Nanny languages.

Comment: See [this Kotlin proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/348) to introduce statics in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1496, accepted):

You place the function in the "companion object".

So the java code like this:

```
class Foo {
  public static int a() { return 1; }
}
```

will become

```
class Foo {
  companion object {
     fun a() : Int = 1
  }
}
```

You can then use it from inside Kotlin code as

```
Foo.a();
```

But from within Java code, you would need to call it as

```
Foo.Companion.a();
```

(Which also works from within Kotlin.)

If you don't like having to specify the `Companion` bit you can either add a `@JvmStatic` annotation or name your companion class.

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

> ## Companion Objects
>
> An object declaration inside a class can be marked with the `companion`
> keyword:
>
> ```
> class MyClass {
>    companion object Factory {
>        fun create(): MyClass = MyClass()
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class
> name as the qualifier:
>
> ```
> val instance = MyClass.create()
> ```
>
> ...
>
> However, on the JVM you can have members of companion objects generated
> as real static methods and fields, if you use the `@JvmStatic`
> annotation.  See the [Java interoperability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields) section for more details.

Adding the `@JvmStatic` annotation looks like this

```
class Foo {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun a() : Int = 1;
  }
}
```

and then it will exist as a real Java static function, accessible from
both Java and Kotlin as `Foo.a()`.

If it is just disliked for the `Companion` name, then you can also
provide an explicit name for the companion object looks like this:

```
class Foo {
  companion object Blah {
    fun a() : Int = 1;
  }
}
```

which will let you call it from Kotlin in the same way, but
from java like `Foo.Blah.a()` (which will also work in Kotlin).

Comment: In Kotlin it will be `fun a(): Int { return 1 }` or even `fun a(): Int = 1`

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev _or_ even `fun a() = 1`.

Comment: What do Factory mean?

Comment: @BagusAjiSantoso `Factory` is the _name_ of the companion object - but what can that be used for? I have no idea, but I was interested so I created a question dedicated to that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45853459/221955.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson how about static methods which return generic type T?

Comment: @AliMehrpour As far as I can tell there is no difference needed for functions returning a value of generic type. Did you have a particular issue in mind?

Comment: Why not just defining an object Class type and call the methods just like this?

`object Foo {
     fun a() : Int = 1
}`
As far as I know, the difference here is that with object you are defining a Singleton, thus I don't see any matter to use it.

`Foo.ad()`

Comment: @Yajairo87 Using the companion object rather than a dedicated singleton top level object, provides clearer separation since I believe the visibility rules are different.

Comment: IHMO this is one of the few really ugly things about Kotlin where Java is just way more simple to write and read. Feels just - wrong.  I made multiple Kotlin trainings now and all of my students are just confused about that every single times. The only things more worse are the current implementation of coroutines (vs. dead-simple async/await in C#)

Comment: If this is the accepted answer, it really should go over singleton `object` and varaibles/functions that are outside of classes. In Java there are only 2 paradigms for the concept, static and Enum, in Kotlin there are many that are each more appropriate for certain situations. Also, Interface support on Enum and objects vs no Interface for static.

Comment: @Novaterata there is a great answer by Pablo Baxter much lower in these that covers some of those other options in quite a bit of depth. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975004/221955) And a similar answer by Yogesh Umesh Vaity (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175395/221955). As you say it would be nice to include some of that information here. If they are missing some other option that you are aware of, let me know and I'll add it here.

Comment: -1 Companion object methods are not static. The reference to this object is static - but its contents are regular instance members, complete with inheritance and polymorphism. Quite the opposite of static.

Comment: @Agent_L - did you miss the comment in the quote from the documentation - " on the JVM you can have members of companion objects generated as real static methods and fields, if you use the @ JvmStatic annotation. See the Java interoperability section for more details."? Do you feel I should be calling out the fact that though by default the calls look like static calls in Kotlin,  under-the hood at the JVM level they are still member calls? Can you show a concrete example where this difference is noticeable? I'm truly interested and would happily extend this answer with the information.

Answer (score 250):

[Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#companion-objects) recommends to solve most of the needs for static functions with **package-level functions**. They are simply declared outside a class in a source code file. The package of a file can be specified at the beginning of a file with the package keyword.

**Declaration**

```
package foo

fun bar() = {}
```

**Usage**

```
import foo.bar
```

**Alternatively**

```
import foo.*
```

You can now call the function with:

```
bar()
```

or if you do not use the import keyword:

```
foo.bar()
```

If you do not specify the package the function will be accessible from the root.

If you only have experience with java, this might seem a little strange. The reason is that kotlin is not a strictly object-oriented language. You could say it supports methods outside of classes.

Edit: 
They have edited the documentation to no longer include the sentence about recommending package level functions. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20170621203530/https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#companion-objects) is the original that was referred to above.

Comment: Note that under the hood these "top-level" or "package" functions are actually compiled into their own class. In the above example, the compiler would create a `class FooPackage` with all of the top-level properties and functions, and route all of your references to them appropriately. [More info from jetbrains.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/improving-java-interop-top-level-functions-and-properties/)

Comment: +1 For explaining how to do the equivalent right **in Kotlin** rather than just the mirror equivalent from Java.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer or a mod should update the accepted answer to contain package level functions

Comment: This is the better solution so far. Just wanted to clarify that where you define the function `bar()` doesn't matter the file name, you can name it `BarUtils.kt` or whatever, then as the text says you will import it with with `import <package name>.bar`

Answer (score 63):

**A. Old Java Way :**

1. Declare a `companion object` to enclose a static **method / variable**

   ```
   class Foo{
   companion object {
       fun foo() = println("Foo")
       val bar ="bar"  
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use :

   ```
   Foo.foo()        // Outputs Foo    
   println(Foo.bar) // Outputs bar
   ```

---

---

**B. New Kotlin way**

1. Declare directly on file **without class** on a `.kt` file.

   ```
   fun foo() = println("Foo")
   val bar ="bar"
   ```
2. Use  the `methods/variables` with their **names**. (**After importing them**)

   Use :

   ```
   foo()        // Outputs Foo          
   println(bar) // Outputs bar
   ```

---

Comment: If i m trying to initialize in some other class its gives java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  and I m using var instead of val

Comment: Method calls need to have the ``INSTANCE`` keyword, like this: ``Foo.INSTANCE.sayFoo()``

Comment: I think this solution is the prefered way if you want a `static CLASS` not just `static methdos`. Because with companion objects you still can instantiate the parent class.

Comment: `val` is not static it's equivalent of `static final` in Java

Answer (score 44):

Use **object** to represent val/var/method to make static. You can use object instead of singleton class also. You can use **companion** if you wanted to make static inside of a class

```
object Abc{
     fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
    }
```

If you need to call it from Java:

```
int z = Abc.INSTANCE.sum(x,y);
```

In Kotlin, ignore INSTANCE.

Comment: this was what I was looking for, thanks :D

Comment: In Java I am able to refer an instance variable as class variable without using INSTANCE, I am afraid of this behavior.

Comment: Finally an answer I  can understand thanks

Comment: CAUTION: This will create a singleton Abc object.

Answer (score 27):

This also worked for me

```
object Bell {
    @JvmStatic
    fun ring() { }
}
```

from Kotlin

```
Bell.ring()
```

from Java

```
Bell.ring()
```

Comment: This is great for "utility" classes (which you also need to be able to call from Java code so you can't use top-level functions)! I'm surprised that I had to scroll down so much to find this.

Comment: This solution worked for me, and feels like the cleanest solution to the question, because the usage pattern is the same between Kotlin & Java.

Answer (score 12):

Even though this is a bit over 2 years old now, and had plenty of great answers, I am seeing some other ways of getting "static" Kotlin fields are missing. Here is an example guide for Kotlin-Java `static` interop:

> **Scenario 1: Creating a static method in Kotlin for Java**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> @file:JvmName("KotlinClass") //This provides a name for this file, so it's not defaulted as [KotlinClassKt] in Java
> package com.frybits
>
> class KotlinClass {
>     companion object {
>
>         //This annotation tells Java classes to treat this method as if it was a static to [KotlinClass]
>         @JvmStatic
>         fun foo(): Int = 1
>
>         //Without it, you would have to use [KotlinClass.Companion.bar()] to use this method.
>         fun bar(): Int = 2
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>         println(KotlinClass.foo()); //Prints "1"
>         println(KotlinClass.Companion.bar()); //Prints "2". This is the only way to use [bar()] in Java.
>         println(KotlinClass.Companion.foo()); //To show that [Companion] is still the holder of the function [foo()]
>     }
>
>     //Because I'm way to lazy to keep typing [System.out], but I still want this to be compilable.
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```

Michael Anderson's answer provides more depth than this, and should definitely be referenced for this scenario.

---

This next scenario handles creating static fields in Kotlin so that Java doesn't have to keep calling `KotlinClass.foo()` for those cases where you don't want a static function.

> **Scenario 2: Creating a static variable in Kotlin for Java**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> @file:JvmName("KotlinClass") //This provides a name for this file, so it's not defaulted as [KotlinClassKt] in Java
> package com.frybits
>
> class KotlinClass {
>
>     companion object {
>
>         //This annotation tells Kotlin to not generate the getter/setter functions in Java. Instead, this variable should be accessed directly
>         //Also, this is similar to [@JvmStatic], in which it tells Java to treat this as a static variable to [KotlinClass].
>         @JvmField
>         var foo: Int = 1
>
>         //If you want something akin to [final static], and the value is a primitive or a String, you can use the keyword [const] instead
>         //No annotation is needed to make this a field of [KotlinClass]. If the declaration is a non-primitive/non-String, use @JvmField instead
>         const val dog: Int = 1
>
>         //This will be treated as a member of the [Companion] object only. It generates the getter/setters for it.
>         var bar: Int = 2
>
>         //We can still use [@JvmStatic] for 'var' variables, but it generates getter/setters as functions of KotlinClass
>         //If we use 'val' instead, it only generates a getter function
>         @JvmStatic
>         var cat: Int = 9
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>         //Example using @JvmField
>         println(KotlinClass.foo); //Prints "1"
>         KotlinClass.foo = 3;
>
>         //Example using 'const val'
>         println(KotlinClass.dog); //Prints "1". Notice the lack of a getter function
>
>         //Example of not using either @JvmField, @JvmStatic, or 'const val'
>         println(KotlinClass.Companion.getBar()); //Prints "2"
>         KotlinClass.Companion.setBar(3); //The setter for [bar]
>
>         //Example of using @JvmStatic instead of @JvmField
>         println(KotlinClass.getCat());
>         KotlinClass.setCat(0);
>     }
>
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```

---

One of the great features about Kotlin is that you can create top level functions and variables. This makes it greate to create "classless" lists of constant fields and functions, which in turn can be used as `static` functions/fields in Java.

> **Scenario 3: Accessing top level fields and functions in Kotlin from Java**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> //In this example, the file name is "KSample.kt". If this annotation wasn't provided, all functions and fields would have to accessed
> //using the name [KSampleKt.foo()] to utilize them in Java. Make life easier for yourself, and name this something more simple
> @file:JvmName("KotlinUtils")
>
> package com.frybits
>
> //This can be called from Java as [KotlinUtils.TAG]. This is a final static variable
> const val TAG = "You're it!"
>
> //Since this is a top level variable and not part of a companion object, there's no need to annotate this as "static" to access in Java.
> //However, this can only be utilized using getter/setter functions
> var foo = 1
>
> //This lets us use direct access now
> @JvmField
> var bar = 2
>
> //Since this is calculated at runtime, it can't be a constant, but it is still a final static variable. Can't use "const" here.
> val GENERATED_VAL:Long = "123".toLong()
>
> //Again, no need for @JvmStatic, since this is not part of a companion object
> fun doSomethingAwesome() {
>     println("Everything is awesome!")
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>
>         println(KotlinUtils.TAG); //Example of printing [TAG]
>
>
>         //Example of not using @JvmField.
>         println(KotlinUtils.getFoo()); //Prints "1"
>         KotlinUtils.setFoo(3);
>
>         //Example using @JvmField
>         println(KotlinUtils.bar); //Prints "2". Notice the lack of a getter function
>         KotlinUtils.bar = 3;
>
>         //Since this is a top level variable, no need for annotations to use this
>         //But it looks awkward without the @JvmField
>         println(KotlinUtils.getGENERATED_VAL());
>
>         //This is how accessing a top level function looks like
>         KotlinUtils.doSomethingAwesome();
>     }
>
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```

---

Another notable mention that can be used in Java as "static" fields are Kotlin `object` classes. These are zero parameter singleton classes that are instantiated lazily on first use. More information about them can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

However, to access the singleton, a special `INSTANCE` object is created, which is just as cumbersome to deal with as `Companion` is. Here's how to use annotations to give it that clean `static` feel in Java:

> **Scenario 4: Using `object` classes**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> @file:JvmName("KotlinClass")
>
> //This provides a name for this file, so it's not defaulted as [KotlinClassKt] in Java
> package com.frybits
>
> object KotlinClass { //No need for the 'class' keyword here.
>
>     //Direct access to this variable
>     const val foo: Int = 1
>
>     //Tells Java this can be accessed directly from [KotlinClass]
>     @JvmStatic
>     var cat: Int = 9
>
>     //Just a function that returns the class name
>     @JvmStatic
>     fun getCustomClassName(): String = this::class.java.simpleName + "boo!"
>
>     //Getter/Setter access to this variable, but isn't accessible directly from [KotlinClass]
>     var bar: Int = 2
>
>     fun someOtherFunction() = "What is 'INSTANCE'?"
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>         println(KotlinClass.foo); //Direct read of [foo] in [KotlinClass] singleton
>
>         println(KotlinClass.getCat()); //Getter of [cat]
>         KotlinClass.setCat(0); //Setter of [cat]
>
>         println(KotlinClass.getCustomClassName()); //Example of using a function of this 'object' class
>
>         println(KotlinClass.INSTANCE.getBar()); //This is what the singleton would look like without using annotations
>         KotlinClass.INSTANCE.setBar(23);
>
>         println(KotlinClass.INSTANCE.someOtherFunction()); //Accessing a function in the object class without using annotations
>     }
>
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 11):

### Top-level / `companion object` for `static` properties

**Top-level**

When the properties are somewhat related to a class, define them as top-level properties just before the class declaration:

```
const val MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3
private const val DEFAULT_NAME = "Guest"
private const val MIN_AGE = 16

data class User(val id: String, val name: String = DEFAULT_NAME)
```

This is similar to the `static` properties in Java.

When the properties are completely independent of any class, you can define them as top-level in a separate file without the class.

**`companion object`**

When the properties are closely related to a class and will be used only in that class, define them inside a `companion object`:

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String = DEFAULT_NAME) {
    companion object {
        const val DEFAULT_NAME = "Guest"
        const val MIN_AGE = 16
    }
}
```

---

### Top-level / `companion object` for `static` methods

**Top-level**

Similar to the properties above, when the functions are somewhat related to a class, define them just above the class:

```
fun getAllUsers() { }

fun getProfileFor(userId: String) { }

data class User(val id: String, val name: String)
```

Usage:

```
val userList = getAllUsers()
```

**`companion object`**

When the functions are closely related to a class, define them inside a `companion object`:

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String) {

    companion object {

        fun getAll() { }

        fun profileFor(userId: String) { }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val userProfile = User.profileFor("34")
```

This is similar to the `static` methods in Java.

The top-level functions are often more idiomatic to Kotlin. A better reason to define functions inside the `companion object` is when you are extending a `companion object` with an `interface`. An example of this is shown in the singleton section.

---

### Nested class for `static` class

When the classes with related functionalities belong together, they can be grouped together by nesting:

```
class User(val id: String, val name: String) {
    class UserAccess : UserDao {
        override fun add(user: User) { }
        override fun remove(id: String) { }
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to the `static` nested classes in Java. The `UserAccess` class here implements an `interface` `UserDao`.

Usage:

```
fun main() {
    val john = User("34", "John")
    val userAccess = User.UserAccess()
    userAccess.add(john)
}
```

---

### Singleton `object` for `static INSTANCE`

**Top-level**

When you just want a single object of a class, you no longer need to create a `static INSTANCE` inside a class like in Java. Simply use a top-level `object` declaration:

```
object UserAccess : UserDao {
    override fun add(user: User) { }
    override fun remove(id: String) { }
}
```

Notice also how easy it is to extend an `interface` or a `class` in a singleton.

The code above, under the hood, produces the following `static INSTANCE` singleton pattern in Java (simplified):

```
public final class UserAccess implements UserDao {
   public static final UserAccess INSTANCE;

   public void add(User user) { }

   public void remove(String id) { }

   private UserAccess() { }

   static { INSTANCE = new UserAccess();}
}
```

**`companion object`**

When the singleton is closely related to a class use `companion object`:

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String) {
    companion object : UserDao {
        override fun add(user: User) { }
        override fun remove(id: String) { }
    }
}
```

This way you get more elegant naming: `User.add(john)`. Also, you make the intent clear that this singleton is only used as a utility for the `User` class. You can also use the `object` without the `companion` keyword inside the class, if you want multiple singletons or groups of functions/properties.

---

### `companion object` for `static` factory

Factory functions in Koltin are created using the `companion object`. Factory functions are useful when you want to provide multiple ways to create an object where the object construction process is complex or when multiple constructors are not expressive enough.

For example, the `newInstance()` factory function in the following snippet creates a user by generating the `id` automatically:

```
class User private constructor(val id: Long, val name: String) {
    companion object {
        private var currentId = 0L;
        fun newInstance(name: String) = User(currentId++, name)
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to the `static` factory methods in Java.

The `constructor` is kept `private` but the `companion object` has access to the `constructor`.

In the code above, consistency of the next `id` generation is guaranteed because a `companion object` is a singleton, only one object will keep track of the `id`, there won't be any duplicate ids.

Also notice that companion objects can have properties (`currentId` in this case) to represent state.

Usage:

```
val john = User.newInstance("John")
```

---

### `@JvmStatic` for Java interoperability

The static concept of Java doesn't exist in Kotlin. A `companion object` is an instance of a real `class` called `Companion`. So, when you call the Kotlin code from Java, an object of the `Companion` class is first instantiated behind the scenes. You need to call the function using the `Companion` object in Java:

```
Profile userProfile = User.Companion.profileFor("34");
```

For the idiomatic Java naming and less verbosity, use `@JvmStatic` annotation on that function or property:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun profileFor(userId: String): Profile { }
}
```

The `@JvmStatic` annotation creates a separate pure `static` copy of the `getProfileFor()` function. Now you can use it from Java with regular syntax:

```
Profile userProfile = User.profileFor("34");
```

---

That's it! Hope the examples are useful for your projects.

Comment: Very nicely written and detailed answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
object objectName {
    fun funName() {

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways you can apply static in Kotlin

First make a companion object under class

For ex:

```
class Test{
  companion object{
    fun isCheck(a:Int):Boolean{
      if(a==0) true else false
    }
  }
}
```

you can call this function as

```
Test.Companion.isCheck(2)
```

Another way we can use is to make an object class

```
object Test{
  fun isCheck(a:Int):Boolean{
    if(a==0) true else false     
  }
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: For first usage (i.e. `Test.Companion.isCheck(2)`) IDE shows warnings and say `Companion reference is redundant`. It can be reduced to `Test.isCheck(2)` and the reduced form is more close to java equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass companion object for static method because kotlin don’t have static keyword - Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class name as the qualifier:

```
package xxx
class ClassName {
  companion object {
    fun helloWord(str: String): String {
      return stringValue
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply use this approach

```
object Foo{
   fun foo() = println("Foo")
   val bar ="bar"  
}

Foo.INSTANCE.foo()
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply you need to create a companion object and put the function in it

```
  class UtilClass {
        companion object {
  //        @JvmStatic
            fun repeatIt5Times(str: String): String = str.repeat(5)
        }
    }
```

---

To invoke the method from a kotlin class:

```
class KotlinClass{
  fun main(args : Array<String>) { 
    UtilClass.repeatIt5Times("Hello")
  }
}
```

or Using import

```
import Packagename.UtilClass.Companion.repeatIt5Times
class KotlinClass{
  fun main(args : Array<String>) { 
     repeatIt5Times("Hello")
  }
}
```

---

To invoke the method from a java class:

```
 class JavaClass{
    public static void main(String [] args){
       UtilClass.Companion.repeatIt5Times("Hello");
    }
 }
```

or by adding @JvmStatic annotation to the method

```
class JavaClass{
   public static void main(String [] args){
     UtilClass.repeatIt5Times("Hello")
   }
}
```

or both by adding @JvmStatic annotation to the method and making static import in java

```
import static Packagename.UtilClass.repeatIt5Times
class JavaClass{
   public static void main(String [] args){
     repeatIt5Times("Hello")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Java:

```
public class Constants {
public static final long MAX_CLICK_INTERVAL = 1000;}
```

Equivalent Kotlin code:

```
object  Constants {
const val MAX_CLICK_INTERVAL: Long = 1000}
```

So for the equivalent of Java static methods is object class in Kotlin.

Answer (score 3):

For Android using a string from a single activity to all the necessary activity.
Just like static in java

`public final static String TEA_NAME = "TEA_NAME";`

Equivalent approach in Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val TEA_NAME = "TEA_NAME"
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Another activity where value is needed:

```
val teaName = MainActivity.TEA_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add something to above answers.

Yes, you can define functions in source code files(outside class). But it is better if you define static functions inside class using **Companion Object** because you can add more static functions by leveraging the **Kotlin Extensions**.

```
class MyClass {
    companion object { 
        //define static functions here
    } 
}

//Adding new static function
fun MyClass.Companion.newStaticFunction() {
    // ...
}
```

And you can call above defined function as you will call any function inside Companion Object.

Answer (score 2):

To make it short you could use **"companion object"** to get into Kotlin static world like :

```
  companion object {
    const val TAG = "tHomeFragment"
    fun newInstance() = HomeFragment()
}
```

and to make a constant field use **"const val"** as in the code.
but try to avoid the static classes as it is making difficulties in unit testing using Mockito!.

Answer (score 1):

The exact conversion of the java static method to kotlin equivalent would be like this. e.g. Here the util class has one static method which would be equivalent in both java and kotlin. The use of [@JvmStatic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods) is important.

Java code:

```java
    class Util{
         public static String capitalize(String text){
         return text.toUpperCase();}
       }
```

Kotlin code:

```
    class Util {
        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            fun capitalize(text:String): String {
                return text.toUpperCase()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

except Michael Anderson's answer, i have coding with other two way in my project.

#### First:

you can white all variable to one class.
created a kotlin file named Const

```
object Const {
    const val FIRST_NAME_1 = "just"
    const val LAST_NAME_1 = "YuMu"
}
```

You can use it in kotlin and java code

```
 Log.d("stackoverflow", Const.FIRST_NAME_1)
```

#### Second:

You can use Kotlin's extension function
created a kotlin file named Ext， below code is the all code in Ext file

```
package pro.just.yumu

/**
 * Created by lpf on 2020-03-18.
 */

const val FIRST_NAME = "just"
const val LAST_NAME = "YuMu"
```

You can use it in kotlin code

```
 Log.d("stackoverflow", FIRST_NAME)
```

You can use it in java code

```
 Log.d("stackoverflow", ExtKt.FIRST_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write them directly to files.

In Java (ugly):

```
package xxx;
class XxxUtils {
  public static final Yyy xxx(Xxx xxx) { return xxx.xxx(); }
}
```

In Kotlin:

```
@file:JvmName("XxxUtils")
package xxx
fun xxx(xxx: Xxx): Yyy = xxx.xxx()
```

Those two pieces of codes are equaled after compilation (even the compiled file name, the `file:JvmName` is used to control the compiled file name, which should be put just before the package name declaration).

Comment: You forgot "Kotlin (ugly)" ...
KOTLIN: companion object { val handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {] .....
JAVA: static Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {};

Answer (score 0):

Let, you have a class **Student**. And you have one **static** method **getUniversityName()** & one **static** field called **totalStudent**.

You should declare **companion object** block inside your class.

```
companion object {
 // define static method & field here.
}
```

Then your class looks like

```
    class Student(var name: String, var city: String, var rollNumber: Double = 0.0) {

    // use companion object structure
    companion object {

        // below method will work as static method
        fun getUniversityName(): String = "MBSTU"

        // below field will work as static field
        var totalStudent = 30
    }
}
```

Then you can use those static method and fields like this way.

```
println("University : " + Student.getUniversityName() + ", Total Student: " + Student.totalStudent)
    // Output:
    // University : MBSTU, Total Student: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the static functionality in Kotlin by **Companion Objects**

- Adding **companion** to the object declaration allows for adding the
  **static** functionality to an object even though the actual static
  concept does not exist in Kotlin.
- A **companion object** can access all members of the class too, including the private constructors.
- A **companion object** is initialized when the class is instantiated.
- A **companion object** cannot be declared outside the class.

  ```
  class MyClass{

      companion object {

          val staticField = "This is an example of static field Object Decleration"

          fun getStaticFunction(): String {
              return "This is example of static function for Object Decleration"
          }

      }
  }
  ```

Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class name as the qualifier:

**Output:**

```
MyClass.staticField // This is an example of static field Object Decleration

MyClass.getStaticFunction() : // This is an example of static function for Object Decleration
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JVMStatic` Annotation

```
companion object {

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            EditProfileFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people mention companion objects, which is correct.  But, just so you know, you can also use any sort of object (using the object keyword, not class) i.e.,

```
object StringUtils {
    fun toUpper(s: String) : String { ... }
}
```

Use it just like any static method in java:

```
StringUtils.toUpper("foobar")
```

That sort of pattern is kind of useless in Kotlin though, one of its strengths is that it gets rid of the need for classes filled with static methods.  It is more appropriate to utilize global, extension and/or local functions instead, depending on your use case.  Where I work we often define global extension functions in a separate, flat file with the naming convention: [className]Extensions.kt i.e., FooExtensions.kt.  But more typically we write functions where they are needed inside their operating class or object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no static keyword in kotlin.  kotlin docs recommends to use package-level functions if u want to follow DRY.
    Create a file with **.kt** extension and put your method in it.

```
package p
    fun m(){
    //fun body
    }
```

after compilation **m** will have a signature of **public static final void**

and

```
import p.m
```

☺

Answer (score 0):

**Not a direct answer to the question**
There has been a Kotlin proposal to introduce statics in Kotlin:

- Proposal: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/statics/proposals/statics.md
- Discussion: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/348
- YouTrack Issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968

Answer (score -2):

In Java, we can write in below way

```
class MyClass {
  public static int myMethod() { 
  return 1;
  }
}
```

In Kotlin, we can write in below way

```
class MyClass {
  companion object {
     fun myMethod() : Int = 1
  }
}
```

a companion is used as static in Kotlin.

Answer (score -2):

The kotlin documents provider three ways to do that,
the first is define function in package,without class:

```
package com.example

fun f() = 1
```

the second is use @JvmStatic annotation:

```
package com.example

class A{
@JvmStatic
fun f() = 1
}
```

and the third is use companion object:

```
package com.example

clss A{
companion object{
fun f() = 1
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

All static member and function should be inside companion block

```
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    }

    fun staticMethod() {
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use [Companion Objects - kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

Which it can be shown by first creating that Interface

```
interface I<T> {

}
```

Then we have to make a function inside of that interface:

```
fun SomeFunc(): T
```

Then after, We need a class:

```
class SomeClass {}
```

inside that class we need a companion Object inside that class:

```
companion object : I<SomeClass> {}
```

inside that Companion Object we need that old `SomeFunc` function, But we need to over ride it:

```
override fun SomeFunc(): SomeClass = SomeClass()
```

Finally below all of that work, We need something to power that Static function, We need a variable:

```
var e:I<SomeClass> = SomeClass()
```