# Migration from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have one Android app written in Java but I want to convert it to Kotlin. I have added Kotlin plugin and configured my app's gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I am converting a single file from Java to Kotlin using - code -> convert java file to kotlin

After conversion I am getting this error:

```
Process: com.stockal.app, PID: 10633

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.stockal.app-1/base.apk:classes75.dex)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4972)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1555)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Something with Firebase, although you haven't add any dependency to it? Strange thing.

Comment: I have added all these library - compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

Comment: Just an idea: Kotlin does not have static methods. Maybe you have a static method in Java that simply wasn't converted appropriately. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352684/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-static-methods-in-kotlin

Comment: Just use the same version number through out i.e 10.2.6 @ Sanni Raj

Comment: @xvlcw There is not static method in that file

Comment: @A.N.T after changing version number getting same issue

Comment: where is the error coming from ? is it coming from a method ? @ Sanni Raj ?

Comment: @A.N.T, After installing the app when I open it then getting this issue

Comment: can you please send the build.gradle(Module:app) @ Sannni ?