# How do you make Kotlin static variables and functions for Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-java-interop

Since Google made Kotlin a first class language for Android, there has been an increase in questions relating to how to perform certain things in Kotlin, "Java-esque" style. The most common ones are how to make `static` variables in Kotlin. So how do you make Kotlin `static` variables and functions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**You can't.** Well, at least in a *pure* Kotlin project.

Kotlin has no notion of `static`. The way `static` works in a Kotlin-Java project is by use of annotations on the Kotlin classes to tell the JVM that the desired variable/function should be exposed as a `static` to Java classes.

The following is an example guide for Kotlin-Java `static` interop (answer originally posted in [What is the equivalent of Java static methods in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352684/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-static-methods-in-kotlin/54975004#54975004)):

> **Scenario 1: Creating a static method in Kotlin for Java**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> @file:JvmName("KotlinClass") //This provides a name for this file, so it's not defaulted as [KotlinClassKt] in Java
> package com.frybits
>
> class KotlinClass {
>     companion object {
>         
>         //This annotation tells Java classes to treat this method as if it was a static to [KotlinClass]
>         @JvmStatic
>         fun foo(): Int = 1
>         
>         //Without it, you would have to use [KotlinClass.Companion.bar()] to use this method.
>         fun bar(): Int = 2
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>         println(KotlinClass.foo()); //Prints "1"
>         println(KotlinClass.Companion.bar()); //Prints "2". This is the only way to use [bar()] in Java.
>         println(KotlinClass.Companion.foo()); //To show that [Companion] is still the holder of the function [foo()]
>     }
>
>     //Because I'm way to lazy to keep typing [System.out], but I still want this to be compilable.
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40352734/5318240) provides more depth than this, and should definitely be referenced for this scenario.

---

This next scenario handles creating static fields in Kotlin so that Java doesn't have to keep calling `KotlinClass.foo()` for those cases where you don't want a static function.

> **Scenario 2: Creating a static variable in Kotlin for Java**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> @file:JvmName("KotlinClass") //This provides a name for this file, so it's not defaulted as [KotlinClassKt] in Java
> package com.frybits
>
> class KotlinClass {
>
>     companion object {
>
>         //This annotation tells Kotlin to not generate the getter/setter functions in Java. Instead, this variable should be accessed directly
>         //Also, this is similar to [@JvmStatic], in which it tells Java to treat this as a static variable to [KotlinClass].
>         @JvmField
>         var foo: Int = 1
>
>         //If you want something akin to [final static], and the value is a primitive or a String, you can use the keyword [const] instead
>         //No annotation is needed to make this a field of [KotlinClass]. If the declaration is a non-primitive/non-String, use @JvmField instead
>         const val dog: Int = 1
>
>         //This will be treated as a member of the [Companion] object only. It generates the getter/setters for it.
>         var bar: Int = 2
>
>         //We can still use [@JvmStatic] for 'var' variables, but it generates getter/setters as functions of KotlinClass
>         //If we use 'val' instead, it only generates a getter function
>         @JvmStatic
>         var cat: Int = 9
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>         //Example using @JvmField
>         println(KotlinClass.foo); //Prints "1"
>         KotlinClass.foo = 3;
>
>         //Example using 'const val'
>         println(KotlinClass.dog); //Prints "1". Notice the lack of a getter function
>
>         //Example of not using either @JvmField, @JvmStatic, or 'const val'
>         println(KotlinClass.Companion.getBar()); //Prints "2"
>         KotlinClass.Companion.setBar(3); //The setter for [bar]
>
>         //Example of using @JvmStatic instead of @JvmField
>         println(KotlinClass.getCat());
>         KotlinClass.setCat(0);
>     }
>
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```

---

One of the great features about Kotlin is that you can create top level functions and variables. This makes it greate to create "classless" lists of constant fields and functions, which in turn can be used as `static` functions/fields in Java.

> **Scenario 3: Accessing top level fields and functions in Kotlin from Java**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> //In this example, the file name is "KSample.kt". If this annotation wasn't provided, all functions and fields would have to accessed
> //using the name [KSampleKt.foo()] to utilize them in Java. Make life easier for yourself, and name this something more simple
> @file:JvmName("KotlinUtils")
>
> package com.frybits
>
> //This can be called from Java as [KotlinUtils.TAG]. This is a final static variable
> const val TAG = "You're it!"
>
> //Since this is a top level variable and not part of a companion object, there's no need to annotate this as "static" to access in Java.
> //However, this can only be utilized using getter/setter functions
> var foo = 1
>
> //This lets us use direct access now
> @JvmField
> var bar = 2
>
> //Since this is calculated at runtime, it can't be a constant, but it is still a final static variable. Can't use "const" here.
> val GENERATED_VAL:Long = "123".toLong()
>
> //Again, no need for @JvmStatic, since this is not part of a companion object
> fun doSomethingAwesome() {
>     println("Everything is awesome!")
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>
>         println(KotlinUtils.TAG); //Example of printing [TAG]
>
>
>         //Example of not using @JvmField.
>         println(KotlinUtils.getFoo()); //Prints "1"
>         KotlinUtils.setFoo(3);
>
>         //Example using @JvmField
>         println(KotlinUtils.bar); //Prints "2". Notice the lack of a getter function
>         KotlinUtils.bar = 3;
>
>         //Since this is a top level variable, no need for annotations to use this
>         //But it looks awkward without the @JvmField
>         println(KotlinUtils.getGENERATED_VAL());
>
>         //This is how accessing a top level function looks like
>         KotlinUtils.doSomethingAwesome();
>     }
>
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```

---

Another notable mention that can be used in Java as "static" fields are Kotlin `object` classes. These are zero parameter singleton classes that are instantiated lazily on first use. More information about them can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

However, to access the singleton, a special `INSTANCE` object is created, which is just as cumbersome to deal with as `Companion` is. Here's how to use annotations to give it that clean `static` feel in Java:

> **Scenario 4: Using `object` classes**
>
> *Kotlin*
>
> ```
> // There is no more need for the @file:JvmName() annotation. The object class below already handles the proper naming.
>
> //This provides a name for this file, so it's not defaulted as [KotlinClassKt] in Java
> package com.frybits
>
> object KotlinClass { //No need for the 'class' keyword here.
>
>     //Direct access to this variable
>     const val foo: Int = 1
>
>     //Tells Java this can be accessed directly from [KotlinClass]
>     @JvmStatic
>     var cat: Int = 9
>
>     //Just a function that returns the class name
>     @JvmStatic
>     fun getCustomClassName(): String = this::class.java.simpleName + "boo!"
>
>     //Getter/Setter access to this variable, but isn't accessible directly from [KotlinClass]
>     var bar: Int = 2
>
>     fun someOtherFunction() = "What is 'INSTANCE'?"
> }
> ```
>
> *Java*
>
> ```
> package com.frybits;
>
> class JavaClass {
>
>     void someFunction() {
>         println(KotlinClass.foo); //Direct read of [foo] in [KotlinClass] singleton
>
>         println(KotlinClass.getCat()); //Getter of [cat]
>         KotlinClass.setCat(0); //Setter of [cat]
>
>         println(KotlinClass.getCustomClassName()); //Example of using a function of this 'object' class
>
>         println(KotlinClass.INSTANCE.getBar()); //This is what the singleton would look like without using annotations
>         KotlinClass.INSTANCE.setBar(23);
>
>         println(KotlinClass.INSTANCE.someOtherFunction()); //Accessing a function in the object class without using annotations
>     }
>
>     void println(Object o) {
>         System.out.println(o);
>     }
> }
> ```