# Parsing pdf with Kotlin using a Uri?

Tags: pdf, kotlin, uri, pdfbox

I write Kotlin code in Android Studio. The user chooses a file from the phone (I need to access the content as a string). There I get a Uri?. With that Uri? I can extract text from .csv and .txt files:

```
if (typeOfFile == ".txt" || typeOfFile == ".csv") {
            try {
                val ins: InputStream? = contentResolver?.openInputStream(uriFromSelectedFile)
                val reader = BufferedReader(ins!!.reader())
                textIWant = reader.readText()
```

...

Getting the file type also works fine, but when it comes to opening pdf files, nothing seems to work. I tried using PDFBox from Apache in various ways. The pdf I try to open is a simple onePager and contains only extractable text (can be copied) [like this pdf](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf).

This is one of the things I tried, the phone freezes when the file to open is a pdf:

```
if (typeOfFile == ".pdf") {
            try {
                val myPDDocument:PDDocument = PDDocument(COSDocument(ScratchFile(File(uriFromSelectedFile.path))))
                textIWant = PDFTextStripper().getText(myPDDocument)
```

...

I´ve been trying for days. Does anyone know, how it works in Kotlin?

Comment: Please include the code that you tried, and link to the PDF. Make sure that the PDF has text to extract (try copy & paste from Adobe Reader)

Comment: Hope it`s better now

Comment: Your code looks very suspicious. In Java, loading a PDF is "PDDocument.load(file)". What you're doing is different. I don't know Kotlin, so please find how to call a static method. Seems it isn't easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352684/

Comment: If you managed to correct your code so that the PDF opens and text stripping works, please answer the question yourself, so this will help others.

Comment: I will as soon as it works. Right now I still have no clue how to do it. I am continuing with more research and trying...

Comment: Maybe this could also help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588117/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked using tom_roush.pdfbox and a companion object:

```
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object PdfParser {
    fun parse(fis: InputStream): String {
        var content = ""
        com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(fis).use { pdfDocument ->
            if (!pdfDocument.isEncrypted) {
               content = PDFTextStripper().getText(pdfDocument)
           }
        }
        return content
    }
}
```

Calling the parse function of the companion object:

```
val fis: InputStream = contentResolver?.openInputStream(uriFromSelectedFile)!!
textIWant = parse(fis)
```

Comment: Great that you got it to work! Don't forget to close "fis" (unless Kotlin does this automatically).