# Idiomatic way for named constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Java I have following class

```
public class Instruction {

    public static Instruction label(String name) {
        return new Instruction(Kind.label, name, null, 0);
    }

    public static Instruction literal(int value) {
        return new Instruction(Kind.intLiteral, null, null, value);
    }

    public static Instruction literal(boolean value) {
        return new Instruction(Kind.boolLiteral, null, null, value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public static Instruction command(String name) {
        return new Instruction(Kind.command, name, null, 0);
    }

    public static Instruction jump(String target) {
        return new Instruction(Kind.jump, target, null, 0);
    }

    public static Instruction branch(String ifTarget, String elseTarget) {
        return new Instruction(Kind.branch, ifTarget, elseTarget, 0);
    }

    private final Kind kind;
    private final String s1;
    private final String s2;
    private final int value;

    private Instruction(Kind kind, String s1, String s2, int value) {
        this.kind = kind;
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.value = value;
    }
    ...
}
```

How this should be done with Kotlin?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352684/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-static-methods-in-kotlin, for a more general discussion on static functions in Kotlin.

Comment: Also, maybe it would be worth using a sealed class instead of a `Kind` enum, and this would even eliminate the need for static factory functions + it would add type safety on what properties are meaningful or not in each case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do this pretty much the same in Kotlin, but by using a companion object:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val instruction = Instruction.literal(42)
}

class Instruction private constructor(...) {
    companion object {
        fun label(name: String) = Instruction(Kind.label, name, null, 0)
        fun literal(value: Int) = Instruction(Kind.intLiteral, null, null, value)
    }

    ...
}
```

Please read [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

@broot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76940036/1540818) is the correct Kotlin equivalent of the Java code. However, in Kotlin we can do better.

You're implicitly thinking of different subtypes of `Instruction` here (which is clearly shown by the `Kind` enum) but without *really* defining those types. For each of those subtypes, the `s1`, `s2`, and `value` properties may or may not mean something. Instead, use a sealed class or interface, and only define properties where they actually make sense:

```kotlin
sealed interface Instruction {
    data class Label(val name: String) : Instruction
    data class IntLiteral(val value: Int) : Instruction
    data class BooleanLiteral(val value: Boolean) : Instruction
    data class Command(val name: String) : Instruction
    data class Jump(val target: String) : Instruction
    data class Branch(val ifTarget: String, val elseTarget: String) : Instruction
}
```

Then, each time you would have used the `kind` property, you would instead just use an `is` check. For instance, `if (thing is Interface.Command) { ... }` or most likely a `when` expression with all possible subtypes, which the compiler will check for type safety.

Thanks to Kotlin's flow typing, each type-checked branch (in `if` or `when`) will make the relevant properties available (such as `value`, `ifTarget`, `name`, etc.).

---

Note: alternatively, literals could even be generic:

```
data class Literal<T>(val value: T) : Instruction
```